# Paypal php MySQL integration tutorial

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I have a complete automatic notification system running on my web page, that is a simple PHP script which search for emails in a database and then send an email to each one, all of this using a Cronjob. The thing is that now i want to transform my free service into a pay one. I want to use PayPal, for a while I've been using it for donations, but now i want it to do monthly payments, and every time the user pays a month a new value enter in the database so the PHP script can know if the user pay or not in order to send or not the email.

I know how to use the monthly payment system on PayPal, but I can't find any tutorials on how to integrate the checkout process of PayPal to my custom made php script in order to automatically know when my users pays and then do a modification on MySQL. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this link [About IPN and API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code) for paypal , you should set yout IPN in your account first .

Here is a [PHP example](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt)