# can i integrate PayPal payment integration in android application through laravel api?

Tags: android, laravel

i am creating android application and uses laravel api for backend work.
I want integrate paypal integration in android through laravel web api. plz tell me how can i implement?

Comment: Use Paypal SKD, check document to implement in app.

Comment: @Shane it uses for only web and i am integrate through laravel api send link

Comment: @user11708206 visit this link https://medium.com/justlaravel/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel-695063599449

Comment: @BimalPrasadPandey is it possible to integrate paypal in android through laravel api?  https://medium.com/justlaravel/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel-695063599449 this link is for web based integration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paypal php MySQL integration tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907332/paypal-php-mysql-integration-tutorial)